# A property of compact metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, compactness, uniform-spaces

I would like to know if the following property could hold.

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Then for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists some $\delta >0$ and some continuous function $F:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for $x,y\in X$ it holds that $\vert F(x)-F(y)\vert <\delta$ implies $d(x,y)< \epsilon$.

I think such a property could hold if given $\epsilon>0$ we construct a finite open cover of $X$ with some balls of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and then using some partition of unity argument construct a continuous function $F:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which takes a different integer value on each ball of the covering of $X$, an take $\delta =\frac{1}{2}$. Here the difficulty I'm facing is to deal with the points which are in two (or more) balls of the covering.

Is it possible to make this argument work? Could it be easier to construct such a function $F$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for some $n\ge 1$ instead?

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that such a space is second countable. Pick a countable dense set $\{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$ and define $F$ to be a series of functions $f_n$ localized close to $x_n$ (say with distance at most $1/n$). If you can reconstruct from $F$ which of the $f_n$ are nonzero, then you can construct a sequence which allows you to controll exactly what you want.

Comment: To me, it seems reasonable to guess that your property is related to $X$ having [covering dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) less than or equal to $1$ but, to be honest, I didn't think this through much. Let me also mention the [Lebesgue number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) here since the space is compact and that could conceivably be helpful. Apologies if none of this turns out to be relevant!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true, even for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $X = S^n$ be the unit $n$-sphere with its usual Euclidean metric $d$ and choose any $\epsilon < 2$.  If $F : S^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) says there exist antipodal points $x, -x \in S^n$ for which $F(x) =F(-x)$.  So we have $|F(x) - F(-x)| = 0 < \delta$ no matter what $\delta$ is, but $d(x, -x)=2 > \epsilon$.

For your $n=1$ version it reduces to the intermediate value theorem.  Take $X = S^1$ (or $S^m$), let $F : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and let $G(x) = F(x) - F(-x)$.  Pick any $x_0 \in X$.  If $G(x_0)=0$ we are done.  Otherwise we have $G(-x_0) = -G(x_0)$ and so $G(x_0) > 0 > G(-x_0)$ or vice versa. Since $X$ is connected, the intermediate value theorem guarantees some $x_1 \in X$ with $G(x_1)=0$.